# How to update file name after attaching to notes in Dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I am attaching documents to notes on order form.

the requirement is as soon as a file is attached its name should be updated by the order number

For example, if file name is `latestOrders.csv` and the order number is `ABC-123-XYZ` then after attaching the file name should be saved as

```
   ABC-123-XYZ - latestOrders.csv
```

is there any mean to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a pre-create plug-in on annotation to handle this requirement. Identify if the annotation being created is 1) an attachment and 2) is related to an order. If both are true then modify the `filename` property. Here is a super quick code sample of the logic.

```cs
if (entity.LogicalName == "annotation" && entity.GetAttributeValue<bool>("isdocument") == true && entity.GetAttributeValue<string>("objecttypecode") == "salesorder")
{
    //I'm assuming you'll write a method to get the order number/name
    var newFilename = GetEntityName(entity.Attributes["objectid"] as EntityReference, entity.Attributes["filename"] as string);
    entity.Attributes["filename"] = newFilename;
}
```